# Tab not activating in access database form

Tags: ms-access-2016, ms-access-forms

I have a form in Access Database 2016 that when accessed by a button in another form, populates the top part of the form as it should, but does not activate the tabs so that the other information can be entered.  The button control on the first time (Insurance) has this coding.

```
    Private Sub Com_Insurance_Click()
    On Error GoTo err_Com_Insurance_Click

    Dim Master As String

    Master = "Insurance_Master"

    DoCmd.OpenForm Master, acNormal


    exit_Com_Insurance_Click:
        Exit Sub

   err_Com_Insurance_Click:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume exit_Com_Insurance_Click

   End Sub
```

This then opens the form "Insurance_Master" and the top part of this form populates fine.  It's just the tabs created midway on this form that remains non responsive.  The code for this form opening is:

```
    Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    On ERRO GoTo err_Form_Open

    Age_Ins.SetFocus

    Forms!frmMaster_search.Visible = False


    exit_Form_Open:
        Exit Sub

    err_Form_Open:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume exit_Form_Open

    End Sub
```

I am not sure what I am missing, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: No tabs seem to be created "midway". And there is a typo in `ERRO`.

Comment: Thank You Gustav, for catching the typo, I have fixed that.  I am not understanding what you mean by there are no tabs created "midway".  I have the tabs created on my form.

Comment: Can't tell. Your code seems not related to the tabs in any way.

Comment: I wish I could say that I know how to do that but I don't.  I did this watching YouTube video's and no where did any of the video's show or state to code the tabs.

Comment: Then, I guess, your issue is not related to the code posted here.